# How to set file type when it's downloaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this Spring endpoint which returns file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{merchant_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(@PathVariable("merchant_id") Integer merchant_id, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
          File initialFile = new File("/opt/1/Why_Brookfield_Callout_3x.png");
          InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);
          org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
          response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
```

But when I download the file I get type text. 
How I can set the type of there file to .png file?

Comment: [Set the content-type](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

add `produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG` in your `@RequestMapping`

see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html for more mediatypes

So the method definition becomes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{merchant_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
```

Comment: which Java package I need to import for MediaType.IMAGE_PNG?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You need to import org.springframework.http.MediaType